# Umbraco 8 getting a error 500 on develop server but it works on localhost while getting data

Tags: c#, iis, umbraco, http-status-code-500, umbraco8

Hello i try my luck here.
I am developing an app that fetches data from Umbraco, It works on my localhost enviroment. But when i push up the code to our development server then the app when it calls the api gets a 500 error and the site keeps on reloading. My colluege thinks maybe its because i only do checks if the person logged in is a member but not a backoffice user, because the view that aint working is on a admin part of the app. i took two pictures of the error message i get. Anyone have any suggestions or has encountered this before?
[image: what i see when i paste the api adress into the browser and surf there]
[image: how the error looks in console]

Update: well it seems i get this error message a lot on the umbraco tracelogs from the folder logs in app_data : {"@t":"2022-10-10T11:54:07.7434113Z","@mt":"Keep alive failed (at '{keepAlivePingUrl}').","@l":"Error","@x":"System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond "hid the servers Ip-adress"\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.Scheduling.KeepAlive.d__5.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Web\Scheduling\KeepAlive.cs:line 69","keepAlivePingUrl":"http://hidIpAdress/Web/umbraco/api/keepalive/ping","SourceContext":"Umbraco.Web.Scheduling.KeepAlive","ProcessId":2032,"ProcessName":"w3wp","ThreadId":29,"AppDomainId":5,"AppDomainAppId":"LMW3SVC1ROOTWeb","MachineName":"name of the server","Log4NetLevel":"ERROR"}

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 500 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: I mean using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis), it is impossible to find the specific problem from your updated information.